# How to fix Failed to parse docker JSON in spring docker compose?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Getting `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'name': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false') at [Source: (String)` when using spring docker compose module to start the docker-compose.yaml.

**Details:**

1. spring boot version 3.2.3
2. Operating system: Ubuntu WSL
3. Docker Compose version v2.25.0
4. Docker Engine - Community Version: 26.0.0

**Docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db
volumes:
  db:
    driver:
      local
```

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerOutputParseException: Failed to parse docker JSON:

name: classes
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 27017
        published: "27017"
        protocol: tcp
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: db
        target: /data/db
        volume: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: classes_default
volumes:
  db:
    name: classes_db
    driver: local

    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerJson.deserialize(DockerJson.java:81) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerJson.deserialize(DockerJson.java:73) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerCliCommand.deserialize(DockerCliCommand.java:77) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]....
services:
  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      default: null
    ports:
      - mode: ingress
        target: 27017
        published: "27017"
        protocol: tcp
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: db
        target: /data/db
        volume: {}
networks:
  default:
    name: classes_default
volumes:
  db:
    name: classes_db
    driver: local"; line: 1, column: 5]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:2477) ~[jackson-core-2.15.4.jar:2.15.4]... at org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.DockerJson.deserialize(DockerJson.java:78) ~[spring-boot-docker-compose-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestion on how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you recently upgrade to 2.25.0? I see an open issue already with similar behavour on github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/40060.

There is a proposed solution if you downgrade docker compose. Hope this fixes your issue too!

Note: I see that this bug fix goes in, in 2.26.0.